# Lifting a heavy object with multiple people

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, experimental-physics

If an average person can lift say 100 lbs alone, how many pounds can he lift with a friend (the same size)? I've heard each person can lift 3 times his usual amount when with another. Is that scientifically proven and why?

Comment: I think it depends on the size and shape of the object, which affect the balance. For example, try lifting a table by yourself, then try it with a friend.

Comment: What is the shape of the object?  Is the object's center of gravity in the center of the object?  Are the two people on level ground?  Can the two people get a good grip on the object, and can the two people get their feet in "convenient" positions?  The answer depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: A person does not actually become able to lift more weight, but large unwieldly objects are more easily managed from multiple lifting points

Comment: Do you have a source for your "3 times" statement?